# WindowsStore ComboBox SelectedIndex not being properly updated?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, windows-store-apps

I have a ComboBox that is binded to my ViewModel. The SelectedIndex is binded to a property on the ViewModel.

What I want to do is, with some conditions, some of the choices on the Index becomes **invalid** so that when the user tries to select it, it should show an **error message** and **not change the currently selected item.**

On the back-end, all is well. However, on the UI, the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox still changes. The error message shows properly, but then the 'shown' selected item in the combobox is not the proper one (ex. ComboBox is currently 'Item 4', User selects invalid item 'Item 3', shows error, but the ComboBox still shows 'Item 3').

Here is XAML code for reference:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Cover"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Covers}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Cover,
                                              Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Style="{StaticResource Style_ComboBox_CheckSelector}" />
```

And my ViewModel:

```
private int _Cover = 0;
    public int Cover
    {
        get { return _Cover; }
        set
        {
            bool canChangeCover = true;

            if(IfInvalid())
            {
                canChangeCover = false;
                ShowCoversError();

                RaisePropertyChanged("Cover");
            }

            if(canChangeCover)
            {
                _Cover = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Cover");
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

A current workaround I found was using the **OnSelectionChanged** event and doing setting the SelectedIndex to the proper value there if Invalid. Though I'm not sure if that is a good workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way in the first place. If there is an "invalid item", then remove it from ComboBox. Don't present it to the user, just to tell them later that they couldn't select it anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clearer. The "invalid items" occur dynamically. Initially, all of the items are loaded. For example, if the user selects 'Item 4', Items 3 and below should not be selectable anymore, but everything else is still available. If user changes to 'Item 6', then 5 and below should not be selectable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to take advantage of the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBoxItem`. Just modify the `ItemsSource` binding to point to a list of `ComboBoxItem`.

C#:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Covers = new List<ComboBoxItem>
        {
            new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Item 1", IsEnabled = true },
            new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Item 2", IsEnabled = true },
            new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Item 3", IsEnabled = true },
            new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Item 4", IsEnabled = true }
        };
    }

    public List<ComboBoxItem> Covers { get; set; }

    private int selectedIndex;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedIndex != value)
            {
                foreach (var cover in Covers)
                {
                    if (Covers.IndexOf(cover) < value)
                    {
                        cover.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }

                selectedIndex = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Covers}" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If you want to keep a collection of your data models in C#, you could implement an `IValueConverter` to project a list of `Cover` into a list of `ComboBoxItem`. You could also create a new class that inherits from `ComboBoxItem` and adds some additional dependency properties if you need to bind more values to your control template. For instance, I toyed around with this:

```
public class CoverComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Description
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
            this.Content = value;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(CoverComboBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

It's worth noting that to maintain a nice separation of concerns, I would usually prefer binding a model property directly to the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBoxItem`. Unfortunately, to make that work you'd need to setup the binding inside of `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle`. Unfortunately, declaring bindings there isn't supported. There are some workarounds I've seen, but the complexity of implementing them is a lot more than the solution I've described above.

Hope that helps!